# Configure TFS Autodeploy to destination server via proxy server

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, proxy

I have a requirement to set up TFS build that auto deploys build deployment result to a remote server location/folder. In order to access this remote deployment folder, I would need to first access a proxy server A, and then from the proxy, I am then able to access machine where the deployment location/folder is located. How do I set this up on TFS please? How do I set up a build that on success makes the two jumps required to get to the deployment destination? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this with the Build server. Its for compiling and testing your code. If you look at Release Management for TFS2013 you can configure a deployment to execute how you describe fairly easily.

http://nakedalm.com/installing-release-management-server-tfs-2013/